# Need LWJGL Setup Guide For Eclipse

Tags: java, lwjgl

Every time I look online the download is not in the same format as the current version, which leads to following the instructions and not being able to use the libraries I need. I'm new to lwjgl but fluent in java if someone could help me set up lwjgl I would be every appreciative. More specifically, the download is not broken up into folders like many that I see in tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rightclick on Project > Properties > Java Build Path > add exterlnal jars...

Now navigate to the downloaded and extracted LWJGL-Folder and select all .jar files inside. And press Add and then Apply. Now it should work fine.